# How do you update multiple values in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

How do you update multiple values?

```
predictions=Fixture_prediction.query\
   .filter_by(user_id=user_id)\
   .update(request.form['home_score'],request.form['away_score'])
```

This is the error I get:

```
ArgumentError: Valid strategies for session synchronization are False, 'evaluate' and 'fetch'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're supposed to use a dictionary with name:value pairs:

```
query.update({'home_score': request.form['home_score'], 
              'away_score': request.form['away_score']})
```

However, keep in mind that this update will bypass all Python based cascading and will not trigger the before_update and after_update events.

Answer (score 1):

So far I haven't seen any examples for a multiple field update.  But if it's possible looks like you just need to identify which columns are being updated.  Try this...

```
.update({"column1": request.form['home_score'], "column2" : request.form['away_score']})
```

Hope this helps!